# Two modal forms with PHP and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two modals *(#U and #R)* in the same HTML page and there is a form each in both of them with different action and different submission.

Both modals open and close sweet, but the second modal submission doesn't work *(#R in this case)*.

I tried to replace #R with #U, then the submission of #U doesn't work (instead of #R before the change).

```HTML
<div class="modal" id="U" style="width:50%;">

    <span class='span3'> X </span>

    <div class="container">

        <form onsubmit="return validateForm3()" action="usersReport.php" method="post">
                <!-- some inputs here -->
                <input type="submit" value="عرض التقرير" name="report3">
        </form>
        
    </div>
    
</div>


<div class="modal" id="R" style="width:50%;">

    <span class='span2'> X </span>
    
    <div class="container">
    
        <form onsubmit="return validateForm2()" action="retirsReport.php" method="post">
            <!-- some inputs here -->
            <input type="submit" value="عرض التقرير" name="report2">
        </form>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

the script in the same page:

```HTML
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.U').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#U').css("display", "block");
        });

    });
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.span3').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#U').css("display", "none");

        });
    });
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.R').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#R').css("display", "block");

        });

    });
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.span2').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#R').css("display", "none");

        });
    });

    function validateForm2() {
        //some code here
    }

    function validateForm3() {
        //some code here
    }
    
</script>
```

Comment: There's too much code missing for a proper diagnosis of the problem. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We need, at least, see how you handle form submissions.

Comment: Please share *validateForm3()* and *validateForm2()* functions

Comment: @Pippo thanks a lot the error was in these function and i discover it when you mention it. the error was i use the same id for error messages for both forms !

Comment: @shiva: Add that as your answer and then (after a short period of time it's possible) mark it with the green check mark so that it is visible it is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discover the problem, the error was I used the same id for error messages (html elements) for both forms in *validateForm3()* and *validateForm2()* functions !